# Javascript, Ajax : Bad Request 400

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on ASP Net Core Project and I'm trying to send to my controller with JQuery Ajax function from a partial view modal, parameters.

The recovered URL is correct for example : `http://localhost:44321/Validations/ValidationRefuse?ficheId=24&commentaire=Commentaire%20de%20test`

But it's always : 
***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)***

**My Javascript :**

```
    $("#buttonRefusFiche").click(function (e) {
        ficheId = $("#ficheId").val();
        commentaire = $("#inputCommentaire").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Validations/ValidationRefuse?ficheId=" + ficheId + "&commentaire" + commentaire,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/html',
            cache: true,
            success: function () {
                alert("Validation refusée.");
            },
            error: function () {
            }
        })
    });
```

**My C# method :**

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ValidationRefuse(int ficheId, string commentaire)
        { ... }
```

**My Partial View :**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Validez-vous cette fiche ?</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-circle" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
        <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
    </button>
</div>
<form asp-controller="Validations" asp-action="ValidationParResponsable" asp-route-id="@Model.FicheId" asp-route-eId="@Model.EnseignantId">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" id="ficheId" asp-for="FicheId" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="EnseignantId" />
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="EtatId" />
            <label class="control-label font-weight-bold">Commentaire :</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="inputCommentaire" asp-for="Commentaire" placeholder="Votre commentaire"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="buttonRefusFiche">Refuser</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Valider</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

I hope it's understandable, thanks for your responses. :)

Comment: Put the request data in the body instead of the URl, or add `[FromQuery]` attributes to the parameters in the action

Comment: Remove `contentType:` - you're not sending html.  You may be mixing this up with `dataType` which is the response type while `contentType` is how you're *sending* the data (which you're not as there's no data as it's in the url).

Comment: I resolved this problem, I just needed to remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]  from my controller

Answer (score 0):

When you use a POST request you have to send the parameters in the body of the request, not in the URL like that :

```
  $("#buttonRefusFiche").click(function (e) {
            ficheId = $("#ficheId").val();
            commentaire = $("#inputCommentaire").val();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Validations/ValidationRefuse",
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                dataType : "html",
                data : {
                    ficheId : ficheId,
                    commentaire : commentaire
                },
                cache: true,
                success: function () {
                    alert("Validation refusée.");
                },
                error: function () {
                }
            })
        });
```

I also changed the contentType and added dataType.

For more information about ajax Post [see documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: Thank, I tried but always the same response : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) :/